# Does transubstantiation teach that the Son regularly returns physically?

Tags: catholicism, christology, incarnation, transubstantiation

Is Catholicism's accidents and species/transubstantiation teaching that the Son of God, our Lord Jesus Christ, returned or regularly returns physically, with a second, mute, nonhuman, physical appearance? (Rather than that He **incarnates** again, often, as bread and wine?)

And relatedly: what would Catholicism say is the point of such a phenomenon? (Or would it say simply that it **is**?)

Comment: Related - https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/30323/do-catholics-believe-that-they-are-actually-eating-the-body-of-christ-does-this/30327#30327

Answer (score 2):

He can't "incarnate again" because His sacred humanity and divinity cannot be separated since when He assumed flesh in the womb of the Blessed Virgin Mother Mary.

Council of Toledo (685 A.D.), [Denzinger 2](http://denzinger.patristica.net/denzinger/#n200)83:

> In this Son of God we believe there are two natures, one of divinity, the other of humanity, which the one person of Christ so united in Himself that **the divinity can never be separated from the humanity, nor the humanity from the divinity**.
> <sub>In quo Dei Filio duas credimus esse naturas; unam divinitatis, alteram humanitatis, quas ita in se una Christi persona univit, ut nec **divinitas ab humanitate, nec humanitas a divinitate possit aliquando seiungi**.</sub>

<sup>cf. pt. 2, ch. 1, §3, "Thesis II: The Logos never even for an instant dissociated Himself from His manhood." of *[Christology: A Dogmatic Treatise on the Incarnation](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=3783)* by Pohle</sup>

---

Christ is present after consecration not as though He departed from heaven and returned to earth but "[after the manner of substance](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/TP/TP076.html#TPQ76A5THEP1)" (*secundum modum substantiæ*).

Comment: Thank you Geremia. It's **neither** Him returning nor body, blood, soul, divinity, and humanity of our Lord Jesus Christ (therefore the whole Christ) **contained** (CCC 1374), reincarnated (inplantated?), in a new, different, bread/wine body. Since after "consecration," I understand, bread/wine are but an unreality, mirage, disguise anyway (so that folks won't sicken? cf Jn 6:52, 60, 66-67). Christ's real living human body; His real Second Coming; His real Spirit **are** real or substantiated by faith. Your phrase "after the manner of substance" maybe is meant to affirm rather than to explain.

Comment: @WalterSmetana After consecration, only the appearances of wine and blood remain.