# Does the Catholic Church have any teaching on cannibalism?

Tags: catholicism, morality, catholic-catechism, catholic-bible, cannibalism

**Does the Catholic Church have any teaching on cannibalism?**

I wasn't able to find much about it.

Comment: What research have you done?

Comment: Somewhat related: "[Do Catholics believe that they are actually eating the body of Christ? Does this make them cannibals?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/30323/1787)"

Answer (score 2):

**Does the Catholic Church have any teaching on cannibalism?**

Under normal circumstances, it is sinful to mutilate a human person who has died. This is plain logic and the the courts treat this as a desecration of a human corpse and take it very seriously.

Nevertheless, exceptions have historically happened.

The Oct. 13, 1972 plane crash in the Andes is a notable example.

> Two spokesmen for the Roman Catholic Archdiocese of New York said yesterday that the survivors of a plane crash in the Chilean Andes two months ago “acted justifiably” when they ate parts of bodies of dead companions to keep from starving to death.
>
> Msgr. Austin Vaughan and the Rev. William Smith, pro fessors of theology at St. Jo seph's Seminary in Yonkers, declared in a statement issued in response to inquiries: “A person is permitted to eat dead human flesh if there is no feasi ble alternative for survival.”
>
> Twenty‐nine persons died in the Oct. 13 crash of an Uru guayan Air Force plane or later in an avalanche. **The 16 survivors, all Roman Catholics, spent 69 days staving off death from starvation and below‐zero temperatures. To stay alive they ate parts of the bodies of the dead.**
>
> The comparison was termed “not unreasonable” by the two Catholic theologians. They said that there was a “serious obli gation” to show respect for the dead and that eating human flesh would be a breach of this obligation “in [almost all cases.”
>
> Cannibalism would be justifiable, they held, if there were no alternative.
>
> [Two Catholic Aides Defend Cannibalism In Chilean Air Crash](https://www.nytimes.com/1972/12/28/archives/two-catholic-aides-defend-cannibalism-in-chilean-air-crash.html)

Answer (score 1):

St. Thomas Aquinas, in [*Super Sent.* lib. 4 d. 10 q. 1 a. 1 arg. 1](https://aquinas.cc/la/en/%7ESent.IV.D10.Q1.A1.Obj1), says

> to eat the flesh of a man suggests a certain bestial cruelty and an irreverence for what is eaten.
> <sub>manducare carnes hominis sonat in quamdam bestialem crudelitatem manducantis, et irreverentiam manducati.</sub>